# OSX QPushButton Text Alignment

Tags: python, macos, alignment, pyqt4, qpushbutton

When rendering a QPushButton using PyQt4 on OS X 10.10.5, the text is not centered in the button. Instead, the text appears to be aligned with the top edge of the button.

[image: example screen shot]

I tried:

```
self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("text-align: center")
```

but that had no apparent effect. Also, I do not see this problem when running the same code on Linux.

How can I vertically center QPushButton text on OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the opposite problem, my text aligns to the bottom, I pushed it to the center by adding `padding-bottom: 1px;`.